# MSMQ integrated with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a WCF MSMQ service-client application. The client will sending data to service over WCF via MSMQ. I try to integrate the application with an oracle database. When the service gets data from the client, I want the service to insert the data into the oracle database immediately. Some of the data can be inserted successfully, some fails with an error:

> ORA-24434: OCIStmtRelease called before OCIStmtPrepare2.

I already searched the error notification keyword on google, but I couldn't find the solution yet to fix my problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please use proper casing and try to write in full sentences when posting here. Also try not post urgency requests when asking a question here. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using ODP.net to talk to Oracle? Also, your problem is unlikely to be caused by MSMQ or WCF so I have removed these tags.